# Employer Submission Preferences - Company site vs third party sites

Tags: hiring-process, applications

When I was composing my application for a position, I saw the position listed on my University Career Services website and the same position listed directly on the company website. Direct submittal through the company website does not let me attach a cover letter but only a basic applicant profile.

Do hiring managers have a preference for how the application is submitted - Directly through the company website or through a third party such as Career Services at my university?

I am a graduate student with a MS degree and am looking to work full time in financial services industry.

Comment: Everyone is different. Hopefully your school has some level of approval from the company if they accept applications for them.

Comment: Could the down-voters on this post explain why you down voted this post? The question is definitely within the scope and fairly specific also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In larger organizations, hiring managers generally don't know how an application was submitted.  In the vast majority of cases applications are vetted by an HR department and then passed onto the manager.   Therefore the manager often won't know (or care) which avenue was taken to submit the application.

In your case, I think you're better off using an option that allows you to attach a cover letter if one exists.  This may be useful background for the hiring manager if your information makes it that far.